# ModalPopupExtender loses dynamically-added table rows on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

VS 2013, ASP.NET 3.5 VB.NET

Page has multiple ModalPopupExtender controls for different popups.  One of these popups fills a table with CheckBoxControls and descriptions for up-selling items.

Page Code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
    [snip]
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender 
            runat="server" 
            ID="mpeUpsell"
            popupControlID="pUpsell" 
            CancelControlID="bGoBack" 
            BackgroundCssClass="custBackground" 
            PopupDragHandleControlID="phDragUpsell"
            TargetControlID="bHidden" 
            Enabled="True"  />
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pUpsell" style="display:none;">
            <div runat="server" class="custPopup">
                <div runat="server" id="phDragUpsell">
                    <h3 style="text-align:center;">
                        <asp:Label 
                            ID="lUpsellHdr" 
                            runat="server"
                            Text="Check Out these Add-Ons" />
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <asp:Label 
                    ID="lAddOnsText" 
                    runat="server" />
[snip]
                <asp:Table 
                    ID="tItems" 
                    runat="server"
                    style="border: 1px solid black;">
[snip]                            <asp:Button ID="bNext" runat="server" Text="Next ---&gt;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
```

The table tItems is populated like so:

```
                    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                        tr = New TableRow()
                        tc = New TableCell()
                        Dim sName As String = "cbItem_" & CInt(dr("ITEM_ID"))
                        Dim cb As New CheckBox()
                        cb.ID = sName
                        cb.Text = dr("ITEM_DESC").ToString.Trim
                        If CInt(dr("UGICheckOFF")) = 1 Then
                            cb.Checked = True
                        Else
                            cb.Checked = False
                        End If
                        [snip formatting]
                        tc.Controls.Add(cb)
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc)
                        tc2 = New TableCell()
                        Dim sPrice As String = String.Format("{0:C}", dr("ITEM_PRICE"))
                        tc2.Text = sPrice
                        [snip formatting]
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc2)
                        tItems.Rows.Add(tr)
                    Next
```

The table populates perfectly and shows when I use code-behind to show the mpeUpsell ModalPopupExtender.

The bNext button's handler looks like this:

```
Protected Sub bNext_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bNext.Click
    If iItemArray IsNot Nothing Then iItemArray = Nothing ' get rid of it
    ' Handle the Next Button
    Dim iCartID As Integer = -1
    iCartID = CInt(Session("CartID"))
    ' iterate the items and add each to cart if not already in cart
    iItemArray = New ArrayList()
    For Each tr As TableRow In tItems.Rows
        For Each tc As TableCell In tr.Cells
            For Each ctl As Control In tc.Controls
                If TypeOf (ctl) Is CheckBox Then
                    Dim cb As CheckBox = CType(ctl, CheckBox)
                    If cb.Checked Then
                        'if there are checks create array of item IDs checked.
                        Dim itemid As Integer = CInt(cb.ID.Replace("cbItem_", ""))
                        iItemArray.Add(itemid)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
[snip]
End Sub
```

When the handler is executed, tItems.Rows.Count is ZERO and the ForEach simply falls through because the table rows are gone.

It is obvious that I have missed something; I just cannot figure out what I have missed.

Thanks, 
John.

Comment: Can you check the order in which table population and button click handler are called? I think table populates too late.

Comment: I think that it was losing the information in the asp Table.  I therefore switched to a GridView and set up the columns for the upsell items.  That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to abandon the asp table because it is not stateful in this instance.  Instead, I used a gridview and bound a datatable to it, and am able to retrieve the values.

Thanks.